# Video size is too small while starting the video in flowplayer

Tags: php, jquery, video, mp4, flowplayer

I am using flow player to play mp4 files in my site. But when I'm playing less then 10 seconds video then at starting video is too small after 2 seconds only it is showing the full width.

I have tried 3 videos

1. 4 Seconds
2. 10 Seconds
3. 12 Seconds

1,2 are having problem while 3 is not (Working fine).

Below link contains images for demonstration.

http://1drv.ms/1pe5Yrh

I have tried below code in flow player function

```
clip: {
       scaling : 'scale', // Used all options available in in this parameter
       autoPlay: false,
       provider: 'pseudo',
       autoBuffering: false
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to use another player to detect where the problem is? For example you can try to use VLC player and check how the 1 and 2 videos works.

Comment: @KryDos I had treid in VLC Player and other players also all videos are fine but .. in flowplayer (jquery plugin).. It is not playing

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't found any solution by using flash player, but I'm using flowplayer5 with flash fallback :)